# How do I use conditionals to differentiate between Page and Subpage in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have been using conditionals to be able to tell if I'm on a page or a subpage of that page, but I cannot for the life of me get the code to do *one* thing if I'm on the master page,and *another* thing if I'm on a subpage of that master page. This is what I have been using so far:

```
if ( is_page('3') || $post->post_parent == '3' ){}
```

Does anyone know how to check for page and subpage? In ExpressionEngine, I would use the URL slugs, but I'm not sure how to do this in WordPress. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this from [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

> Testing for sub-Pages
>
> There is no is_subpage() function yet,
>   but you can test this with a little
>   code:
>
> Snippet 1

```
<?php

 global $post;     // if outside the loop

 if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
 {
     // This is a subpage

 } else {
     // This is not a subpage
 }
?>
```

---

Using the URL

```
$url = '/shop/';
$url2 = '/shop/category/accessories';

function isSubPage( $page, $url = null ) {

    if ( strtolower(trim( $url, '/' )) == $page ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

var_dump(isSubPage( 'shop', $url )); //false
var_dump(isSubPage( 'shop', $url2 )); //true
```

for the second argument you're goign to want to put $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or whatever variable you can get the request from

```
var_dump(isSubPage( 'shop', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));
```

Comment: Hrm, that's what I have been using to test against specific parents and children pages. Maybe this is different, since I am using the Shopp plugin. I have a parent page of .com/shop/ and then clicking a category of products brings me to .com/shop/category/accessories/ and the current code isn't working. I was hoping to be able to check against URLs… any idea on how I could achieve that?